# What is the cvc number for paypal dummy credit card in sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

PayPal Developers does not mention any CVC (3 digit number at the back side of credit card) to be used with the dummy credit card numbers provided in the test sandbox account. So, what CVC number should be entered to test the gateway?
Refer:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

Answer (score 3):

Since these are test cards any valid 3 digit CVC can be used.